# Unexpected syntax error in "Python 2.7.1 IDLE" (Works well with canopy!)

Tags: python, python-2.7, canopy

[image]
[image]

As You see at the 2 pics the iteration loop works well with canopy but with IDLE Python 2.7.10 says: *Syntax error*

Why?

Comment: Because print with`()` is python 3+ syntax!!!

Comment: @WoodChopper adding `()` will work in Python 2.x

Comment: Removing `()` this will work in 2x

Comment: @WoodChopper Even with " " or ' ' 
It gives me the same !!

Comment: I tried just 
print ('Goodbye!') 
and It works well
but with the iteration loop 
Syntax error !!!
wierd !

Comment: It would be a big improvement if you could copy and paste the text of your issue into the question, rather than only providing images

Comment: @Wondercricket That's not really true. Python 2's `print()` and Python 3's `print()` are totally different beasts, with the latter being a function call while the former is expanded to `print ()` (print some tuple). Needless to say this can give weird, unexpected results on Python 2, and various arguments to the Python 3 `print()` function won't work at all. Better to just `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist You are correct, `print` in Python 2 and 3 work completely different. However it should not be the cause of the `SyntaxError` with the OP's code.

Comment: @Blckknght 
Sorry , I'm new here It's my first question :)

Comment: The `print` needs to be indented to the same level as the `while`

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like IDLE was confused by how you entered multiple statements. You need to enter a blank line after the indented suite of the while loop so it knows the statement is over (and that there's not an `else` block attached). You'll know you've finished the statement when the `>>>` prompt appears again.

```
>>> while ...
        # stuff here
        # more stuff
        # leave a blank line afterwards!

>>> print ('Goodbye!')
```

Your code would work just fine in IDLE if you put it into a module and ran the module. It's only the interactive console that has issues.

Comment: Thanks so much 
can You tell me how to make a blank line 
I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: That depends on how you're entering the code. If you're typing it by hand, just press Enter twice after the last line of the loop. If you're copying and pasting from a source that has the code tightly packed together, that's tougher. You'll need to copy the statements separately, pressing Enter in between manually.

Comment: but then the IDLE will excute the loop before without the statement (print)
I think adding 
else :
        print ('Goodbye!') 

would be better 
or do You have another way ?!

Comment: An else statement could work, though usually you only attach one to a loop where you might or might not be `break`ing out, rather than having the condition become falsey at some point. I think the real question though is why you want the to have both the loop and the print at the end happen at the same time? They're separate statements, so you should run one then run the next one.